# Passing javascript objects with brackets as keys to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, object

Assume I have this object in JavaScript which is built like this:

```
var obj = {};
var fields = ['table_name[field_name]', 'tale_name[field_name_2]']

for(var i; i < fields.length; i++){
    obj[fields[i]] = someBulkOfData;
}
```

when logged in the console, obj will output

```
{
   table_name[field_name]   : {...},
   tabke_name[field_name_2] : {...}
}
```

This works all fine, until I pass the object through PHP by jQuery.ajax().

When I receive my request in PHP, the array looks as follow:

```
[
    ['table_name[field_name']   => ...,
    ['table_name[field_name_2'] => ...
]
```

So what happens here is that somewhere between sending the AJAX-request and receiving the data in PHP, the last square bracket of every key dissappears.

Could someone explain to me why this happens, and if there is a neat way to solve this problem?

I have one criteria for the solution, and that is that I cannot change the keys (as in something like 'table_name\[field_name\]').

Comment: Why can't you change the keys?

Comment: What do you mean 'receive my request in PHP' ?  Please elaborate a bit.

Comment: How do you encode and decode this? I tested it with `JSON.stringify` and `json_decode()`, those handle the keys fine. Is it a GET request? Maybe it helps if you show your `$.ajax()` call.

Comment: fab, that works just fine. -thanks!

Lighthart, what I mean is that i pass the data through an ajaxRequest ($.ajax()), and that the keys in $_REQUEST['obj'] are without the last bracket, as they would be in my JS object.
Cerbus, i can't change the keys because it's part of a bigger framework. I can however find a different solution, but it would be nice if I could use this setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is, thanks to @fab , to encode the data with JSON:

```
$.ajax({
    data : {
        obj:JSON.stringify(obj)
    },
    ...
});
```

In PHP:

```
json_decode($_REQUEST['obj']);
```

This will output a perfectly nice stdClass object, with preserved keys.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using `$.serialize()`?

use serialize to turn a javascript object into a string that can be transmitted with AJAX easily - like this:

```
var ajaxableString = $(obj).serialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve that issue by restructuring your JS object:

```
{
  table_name : {
    field_name_1 : {...},
    field_name_2 : {...}
  },
  another_table : {
    ...
  }
}
```

That way you avoid that weird naming convention.

Also, I suspect you are hiding something from us. There is something (an operation) between the this and PHP, maybe somewhere in your AJAX code, that you are not telling us. Maybe you are serializing this object into a string and passing the string as one query parameter to the server. This serialize step might be the cause.

But just to be sure, you can check the Net section of the debugger and check the request headers if the data sent is formatted perfectly.

As far as I know, [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) accepts a JS object as data, and perfectly converts it into querystrings. By that, you don't need to serialize it manually.

Comment: Ah, you suspected right! I am hiding a lot. It's part of a bigger framework, and the code as I typed above is just an example. I cannot show you the whole process, as that would take some pages.. ;) Request as shown in the net section converts the brackets into %5B and %5D. I went for fab's solution and encoded and encoded the object as JSON, which seems to work. I do find it weird however that I cannot pass an object with those keys through $.ajax without encoding it.